# How div can be on bottom of page and let it grow if content is big

Tags: css, dynamic, height

I read lot of solution, but I don't finalyse my code.
I've a page with header/Content/Footer.
My problem is inside content. 
I want :
 - small content : div draw until 10px above my footer. 
 - Gib content : div grow and when I scroll to bottom I want again 10px between my div and my footer.

Here one of my try : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59t9od18/1/)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
            <img  style="border: 0; height: 150px;" src="http://www.vinaigremalin.fr/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/voiture-qui-sourit.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="contenu Centre">
       <div class="BlocAccueil">

    <div class="AGauche" style="margin:10px;">
        <img src="https://www.themilliardaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/2011-Koenigsegg-Agera.jpg" style="width: 300px;" />
        </div>
    <div>
        Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker
    </div>
</div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="footer Centre">
    text footer
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and css

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
html {
  height: 90%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
}
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', Arial, 'Times New Roman', "Helvetica Neue", "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  min-height: 100% ;
}
.header {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 960px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 150px;
}

.contenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 960px;
  top: 180px;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 0;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #222324;
  color: #fff;
  height: 5%;
}

.Centre {
  text-align: center;
}

.AGauche {
  float: left;
}
.BlocAccueil {
    width: 85%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
}
}
```

It's ok for small content, but not for big content.

I try too : flex/flex-direction:column. Failed.
I try : min-height : ok for big content but not for small content

### UPDATE

I find a simple solution : put a div color above footer.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
<style  >

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
html {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url('http://www.vinaigremalin.fr/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/voiture-qui-sourit.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', Arial, 'Times New Roman', "Helvetica Neue", "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  min-height: calc(100% - 20px) ;
}
.header {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 960px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 150px;
}

.contenu {
position:relative;
width: 960px;
top: 180px;
background-color: white;
min-height: calc(100% - 180px);
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #222324;
  color: #fff;
  height: 25px;
}
.abovFooter{width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 30px;
  }

.Centre {
  text-align: center;
}

.AGauche {
  float: left;
}
.BlocAccueil {
  width: 85%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        My Header
    </div>
    <div class="contenu Centre">
       <div class="BlocAccueil">

            <div class="AGauche" style="margin:10px;">
                <img src="https://www.themilliardaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/2011-Koenigsegg-Agera.jpg" style="width: 300px;" />
            </div>
        <div >
            Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="abovFooter"></div>
<div class="footer Centre">
text footer
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

like [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/59t9od18/3/)

Now, my problem is that the background isn't black but a picture.
With my tricks I need to take part of this picture in my new div. But when you resize this part of picture need follow the background picture (I hope I'm clear)
Then 2 things :
- I can make a dynamic part picture in my trick div
- Find another way...
[here jsfiddle with background-image](http://jsfiddle.net/59t9od18/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search with the trick and a good idea comes ... If I add a div under my content div (class = AbovFooter)...

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
    <style  >

html {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:url('http://www.vinaigremalin.fr/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/voiture-qui-sourit.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  /* version standardisée */
}
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', Arial, 'Times New Roman', "Helvetica Neue", "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  min-height: calc(100% - 20px) !important;
}
.header {
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 150px;
}

.contenu {
    position:relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin : 30px 0 30px;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: calc(100% - 235px);/*180+30*/
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #222324;
  color: #fff;
  height: 25px;
}

.Centre {
  text-align: center;
}

.AGauche {
  float: left;
}

.abovFooter{
  background-color: transparent;
  height:25px;
  }
.BlocAccueil
{
text-align:justify;
padding:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
                My Header
        </div>
        <div class="contenu Centre">
           <div class="BlocAccueil">
                <div class="AGauche" style="margin:10px;">
                    <img src="https://www.themilliardaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/2011-Koenigsegg-Agera.jpg" style="width: 300px;" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="abovFooter"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer Centre">
        text footer
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I woudn't limit the height of the `htlm`or `body` as You have done. It's always better to give them `100% height` and then, limit the height of a container for all your elements (header, footer, and content) .

But I will use your fiddle.

First if you want always 10px distance between your footer and the rest whatever the content of your web you may use:

```
html {
  height:calc(95% - 10px);
}
```

Because the height of your footer is 5%. Now you will always have that 10px margin.

Notice I also set your body to:

```
height:calc(100% - 10px);
```

because you have used 100% not counting the margin-top you set to 10px.

Finally I have added:

```
.page { 
     overflow-X: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

So you can scroll your content if too big and it won’t flow outside your `html` height.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/59t9od18/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want the scroll inside. and when You had text in your sample, it's not the expension isn't in the same size of ".contenu"